# show subsections in toc for multiple sections but not all sections

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

In a beamer presentation toc I would like to show only the section headings for most sections but show also subsections headings for some sections. I know this is easily obtained for the current section only. But I would like to show subsections headings for the current section and another one. Basically, instead of using `hideothersubsections` option, I would need an option where it is possible to specify the numbers of the sections for which to hide subsections hiding. Does this option exist?

Answer (score 1):

You can split your toc into the sections for which you don't want subsections and the ones with subsections:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[sections={1},hideallsubsections]
\tableofcontents[sections={2-3}]
\tableofcontents[sections={4},hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}
    
\section{section title}
\subsection{subsection title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{section title}
\subsection{subsection title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{section title}
\subsection{subsection title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{section title}
\subsection{subsection title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]